# What is faster, counting the number of elements in a table or getting the last record?

Tags: mysql, sql

What is faster, counting the number of elements in a table or getting the last record?

We are talking about MySql here.

Comment: is the table indexed? if so, I believe the rowcount is O(1)

Comment: I want to get the last id. The id is auto increase, and I never delete any of them. So the last id is equal to the number of rows. Want to know which is faster to find out.

Comment: Use count() - assuming that the value of your auto-increment ID will always match the row count is a fairly brittle assumption.

Comment: It still seems to me that you'd be better off getting the last ID instead of counting rows. How can you be sure no row will ever be deleted? What if other people or applications access the database in the future? What if you make a mistake somewhere or accidentally insert 2 rows when you meant to insert 1? Wouldn't you delete the extra? Do you never insert test data? Your application will be much more solid if you just get the last ID.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the table is ISAM, row count is cached and should be returned instantly.

If the table is InnoDB, it can be a little slower.

For more information, see especially this comment:

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/comment-page-1/#comment-106645

Answer (score 4):

I don't know that these two actions really accomplish the same thing. What is it you're trying to do?

Are you trying to determine how many records are in the table? If so, simply getting the last record (and, I assume, using it's ID number as the number of records) wouldn't be accurate. If you've inserted 10 rows, and then you delete rows 3 and 7 then the highest ID is 10 but you only have 8 records.

For the same reasons, counting the records won't give you the highest ID number, because in many cases there will be fewer records than the number indicated by the highest ID.

Also, in terms of speed, I'm pretty sure most methods for counting rows and most methods for determining the last row will both use the table/indexes in similar ways, so I'm not thinking there'd be a huge speed difference.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess here, but provided your table is indexed properly, getting any element is extremely fast.  I would think that getting the last element is faster and would even expect MySQL to actually count all the records when you ask for the record count.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use

`Select count(*) FROM ...`

That is probably the fastest way as the database can do it quickly and the amount of data returned is very small.

Comment: engine=innodb count(*) will be slow for large tables as it requries a full table scan - it's a transactional engine after all. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/12/01/count-for-innodb-tables/